# Convert list of integers (IEnumerable<int>) to list of tuples (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>) of specific length

Tags: c#, algorithm, statistics

I try to solve next exercise:

**Input:** List of integers with `count >= 1;` some positive integer `k`

**Output:** *all possible* tuples of this integers with *length* of `k`;

For instance

**Input:** `{1, 2}; k = 4`

**Output:**

```
{
 {1, 1, 1, 1},
 {1, 1, 1, 2},
 {1, 1, 2, 1},
 {1, 1, 2, 2},
 {1, 2, 1, 1},
 {1, 2, 1, 2},
 {1, 2, 2, 1},
 {1, 2, 2, 2},
 {2, 1, 1, 1},
 {2, 1, 1, 2},
 {2, 1, 2, 1},
 {2, 1, 2, 2},
 {2, 2, 1, 1},
 {2, 2, 1, 2},
 {2, 2, 2, 1},
 {2, 2, 2, 2}
}
```

I tried to create an *array* that contains `k` *copies of input list* and than use `Combinations`:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> elements, 
  int k)
{
    return k == 0 
        ? new[] { new T[0] } 
        : elements.SelectMany((e, i) => elements
              .Skip(i + 1)
              .Combinations(k - 1)
              .Select(c => (new[] { e }).Concat(c)));
}
```

But it takes **too long** when `k > 9`. Is there an algorithm for solving this problem in a **short time**?

Comment: You are going to have `Math.Power(elements.Count(), k)` items; in your case `2**9 == 512` items only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's get rid of *recursion* and have `512` items:

**Code:**

```
//TODO: you may want to declare it as IEnumerable<T[]> Combinations<T> 
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(
  this IEnumerable<T> elements, int k) {

  if (null == elements)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(elements));
  else if (k < 0)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(k));

  T[] alphabet = elements.ToArray();

  // Special cases
  if (alphabet.Length <= 0)
    yield break;
  else if (k == 0)
    yield break;

  int[] indexes = new int[k];

  do {
    yield return indexes
      .Select(i => alphabet[i])
      .ToArray();

    for (int i = indexes.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
      if (indexes[i] >= alphabet.Length - 1)
        indexes[i] = 0;
      else {
        indexes[i] += 1;

        break;
      }
  }
  while (!indexes.All(index => index == 0));
}
```

**Demo:**

```
string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Combinations(new int[] { 1, 2}, 9)
  .Select(line => string.Join(", ", line)));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Outcome:** (`512` records)

```
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1
...
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2
```

Let's generate, say, all `2**20 == 1048576` items (`k = 20`), i.e. more than *1 million* arrays of size `20` :

```
  Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

  sw.Start();  

  int count = Combinations(new int[] { 1, 2 }, 20).Count();

  sw.Stop();

  Console.Write($"{count.ToString()} items at {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds:f0} milliseconds");
```

**Outcome:**

```
  1048576 items at 469 milliseconds
```